# Prometheus: Per hour statistics for a counter

Tags: prometheus

I have a counter, and I have to make a graph which shows per hour data
I am trying to make use of increase function:

```
increase(my_metrics)[60m]
```

Is this the correct approach?
Or some other better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to be the correct approach.

See more details of the "increase" function at the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase).

Answer (score 0):

Could put `increase(my_metrics)[60m]` to record rules, evaluat once every hour, to another metrics name like `my_metrics_increases_houly`. Then use table panel to display it, you will get exactly one point an hour.